# Get meta_value of a specific meta_key from all posts belonging to a specific custom type

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm faced with a situation where I need to fetch meta_value of a specific meta_key from ALL the posts available in WordPress database. Obviously, this results into large number of database queries. Here's how it looks :

```
foreach ( $quiz_takers as $competitor ) {
    $quizzes_user_has_taken = get_post_meta( $competitor, 'quiz_results', true );
    // More stuff happens here. 
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to reduce the number of queries happening via the `get_post_meta()` above.

The only solution I could think of was to directly query the `wp_postmeta` table directly; but not sure what's the right way to do it.

Would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. I thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Querying wp_postmeta would be the way to go:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'quiz_results'");
```

That will get you an array of values for quiz_results across all posts.

Comment: Additionally, I think the we can use the transient API to cache the results if the process runs often enough? I don't think `WPDB::get_col()` caches anything...?

Comment: If there's a particularly large amount of posts, maybe. Keep in mind that `get_post_meta` only caches results across a single page load if you're using it multiple times. It doesn't cache across page loads.

Comment: Interesting, Jacob. I'll be querying about 2000 - 5000 posts and about 10000 posts in the longer run. Will the results be cached even if I'm changing $post_id in `get_post_meta( $post_id )` ? I don't expect the process to run often. Not more than 300 - 500 times on an average day.

Comment: `get_post_meta` doesn't cache results in the db, it just means that if you call `get_post_meta` twice on the page, on the same post/object, it will only make 1 database query for each object, but if you refresh the page it's going to make the same query again (or 10000 queries in your case). If you're querying that many posts, you might want to do it in the background with a cron, so it doesn't bog down page loads, and cache the results with the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). I don't know how fast this query will be though, so you should experiment.

Comment: A fundamantal nuance I was not aware of, concerning `get_post_meta()` cache management, thanks... Do you have some reference discussing about that particularity? If yes, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Under the hood get_post_meta uses the [WP_Object_Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but a meta-only `WP_Query` should do the trick, no?

As in:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'=>'quiz_results',
);

$your_query_name = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then use the standard WP loop to retrieve the posts.

Comment: Hi, no, `WP_Query` will return the posts **filtered by** the `meta_key` you have in your `$args`. It will **not** return post's meta data. So that doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, that will return the 'posts'. I however need the meta_values.